# How to install hla-la package via Conda?

Tags: conda, bioinformatics

I just installed Anaconda today so I am very new to this. I am trying to install **hla-la** through Conda. I can see the package [on the BioConda website](https://anaconda.org/search?q=hla-la). I try the command provided there:

```
conda install -c bioconda hla-la
```

Yet I get a `PackagesNotFoundError`. I was trying to see if maybe the channel it's on is not being searched, but I can't figure out where to find that information. Any ideas?

Comment: That package is only available for **linux-64** platform - is that what you have?  Also, the `-c bioconda` part tells Conda to check that channel, so that shouldn't be the issue.